# Not getting automatic list/menu after clicking tab buttion in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[whenever I am using **jupyter notebook** and typing pd, there is no automatic suggestion for operation to perform .

> please help me how to fix this ?? or is there any other way to do that

I am trying to do by pressing tab but its not working,
then I try and import this-conda install,

```
 -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
```

And after that I import this-

jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland 
this error come please help[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPr9z.png

Comment: yes i import pandas as pd  before writing pd.

Comment: where are you running this? the screenshot doesnt show jupyter notebook open. You have to type `jupyter notebook` in the anaconda prompt which will take you to jupyter

Comment: Also have you pressed the shift tab after the dot ?

Comment: this screenshot is taken after importing those statements in annaconda prompt,and this screenshot is save in paint for sharing with u guys...

Comment: okayyyyyyy....now im getting my answer i hv to use shift-tab after dot.....thanks man

Comment: Bro sometime it works sometimes its not,i follow ur steps i press shift-tab after pd.,hlp me out,? Wht to do now